# 552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I'm not able to send a mail using ovh smtp server and spring integration.

Configuration looks good to me, what am I missing?

```
<int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="myOutboundMailChannelAdapter"
    channel="outboundMailChannel"
    mail-sender="mailSender" />

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="ns0.ovh.net"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="myUsername"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPass"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

following the detailed log:

> DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
> > DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
> > DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "ns0.ovh.net", port 587, isSSL false
> > 220 ns0.ovh.net You connect to mail191 ESMTP
> > DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "ns0.ovh.net", port: 587
> > EHLO Marcello-PC.lan
> > 250-ns0.ovh.net You connect to mail191
> > 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
> > 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
> > 250-STARTTLS
> > 250-8BITMIME
> > 250 SIZE 109000000
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "109000000"
> > STARTTLS
> > 220 ready for tls
> > EHLO Marcello-PC.lan
> > 250-ns0.ovh.net You connect to mail191
> > 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
> > 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
> > 250-8BITMIME
> > 250 SIZE 109000000
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
> > DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "109000000"
> > DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
> > DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
> > DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
> > DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
> > MAIL FROM:
> > 552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist [mail191] (#5.7.1)
> > DEBUG SMTP: got response code 552, with response: 552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist [mail191] (#5.7.1)
> > RSET
> > 250 flushed
> > DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
> > com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist [mail191] (#5.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the formatting of your post hid the email address in the MAIL FROM: line.  What address did you set as the From address of your message?  Based on the error message, it looks like it's using a domain name that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The message you're sending to the outbound adapter needs a `from` header. There's a bunch of headers you can set up...

```
<int-mail header-enricher input-channel="literalValuesInput">
    <to value="test.to"/>
    <cc value="test.cc"/>
    <bcc value="test.bcc"/>
    <from value="test.from"/>
    <reply-to value="test.reply-to"/>
    <subject value="test.subject"/>
    <attachment-filename value="foo.txt"/>
    <multipart-mode value="1"/>
</header-enricher>
```

Of course, email addressed have to be in valid domains for most SMTP servers to accept them.