# Django and Mailgun : 552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)

Tags: django, mailgun, ovh, django-anymail

I'm trying to send mail using Django and Mailgun through the Anymail package and with an OVH server.

I'm currently receiving the `552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)` error.

In [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485192/552-sorry-your-envelope-sender-domain-must-exist-5-7-1), it is suggested that I would need a "from" header, but the response I'm getting seems to show that the header is already included :

```
    "headers": {
      "to": "evenements@mydomain-longversion.org",
      "message-id": "20160915065953.15168.46300.4ABD80EB@mailgun.mydomain.fr",
      "from": "covoiturage@mydomain.fr",
      "subject": "Mail test !"
    },
```

Here is the full response, for reference :

```
{
  "severity": "permanent",
  "tags": [],
  "storage": {
    "url": "https://si.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mailgun.mydomain.fr/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6ImI5OGIyN2QzLTM2MmEtNGJjNi05ZWViLTRlMTA0NTVmYTIxMiIsInMiOiJlNmY5NzZhZTYwIiwiYyI6InNiaWFkIn0=",
    "key": "eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6ImI5OGIyN2QzLTM2MmEtNGJjNi05ZWViLTRlMTA0NTVmYTIxMiIsInMiOiJlNmY5NzZhZTYwIiwiYyI6InNiaWFkIn0="
  },
  "delivery-status": {
    "tls": false,
    "mx-host": "redirect.ovh.net",
    "attempt-no": 1,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 0.9216420650482178,
    "code": 552,
    "message": "552 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)",
    "certificate-verified": false
  },
  "recipient-domain": "mydomain-longversion.org",
  "event": "failed",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "error",
  "timestamp": 1473922798.282194,
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": "postmaster@mailgun.mydomain.fr",
    "sending-ip": "209.61.151.224",
    "targets": "evenements@mydomain-longversion.org"
  },
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "evenements@mydomain-longversion.org",
      "message-id": "20160915065953.15168.46300.4ABD80EB@mailgun.mydomain.fr",
      "from": "covoiturage@mydomain.fr",
      "subject": "Mail test !"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "evenements@mydomain-longversion.org"
    ],
    "size": 643
  },
  "recipient": "evenements@mydomain-longversion.org",
  "id": "TfJKwpoZQq6bM-MW5sm6nA"
}
```

And here is my Django code :

```
def SendTestEmail(request):
    if request.user.is_staff and settings.DEBUG == True :
        send_mail(
            subject='Mail test !',
            message='''Bonjour {}, votre email a bien été envoyé.'''.format(request.user.get_full_name()),
            recipient_list=['evenements@mydomain-longversion.org',],
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        messages.success(request, 'Email correctement envoyé !')
    return redirect('rideshare_event_list')
```

Comment: Have you created DNS records for `mailgun.mydomain.fr`? We can't check, because you're not using the real domain in your question. See the docs on [verifying your domain](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain).

Comment: Alasdair, I think so, my mailgun dashboard says that `mailgun.mydomain.fr` is active. Do I need to change my sender email to, i.e., covoiturage@mailgun.mydomain.fr ?

Comment: I think it's worth trying `covoiturage@mailgun.mydomain.fr`, but I'm not sure whether it will make any difference.

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry, I don't know how you can send mail from `domain.fr` instead of `mailgun.domain.fr`, or whether that's possible.

Comment: Oops. You can go ahead and post this as an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `covoiturage@mailgun.mydomain.fr` as your from address instead of `covoiturage@mydomain.fr`.

I'm afraid I'm not sure whether it's possible to use `covoiturage@mydomain.fr` as the from address.